# How to change colors as user in Redhat linux server (iterm2, ssh)

Tags: ssh, rhel, osx, iterm2, ansi

My school server is Redhat 7.4 and I really hate the default colors which are printed in ls. bold and dark colors with a black backround is really hard for me to see any file names.

I am currently using os x and iTerm2 for SSH. When connecting to my own debian server, ssh automatically changes server colors to be the ANSI colors I chose from iTerm settings. But in Redhat this doesnt happen. Also most of the guides in the internet require changing something from /etc.., which I am of course not able to do.

So is it possible to change the colors just for my user and locally without being sudoer?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an alias in your ~/.bashrc:

```
alias ls="ls --color=always"
```

Yo can also set the environment variable LS_COLORS, check online for examples, just look for it with your $search_engine of choice, make sure you `export` it if you add it to your ~/.bashrc

```
export LS_COLORS="..."
```

Basically, read about `~/.bashrc`, and what you can do with it, remember `alias` is your friend in the command line.

Comment: There is no .bashrc file. Can I just create one?

Comment: Yes, you can, just open your editor or use `echo` and `>>`.